# Add a css class of container depending on its children's classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs on a page. I need to add various classes to "container" depending on what its children's class is.
Let's say, if there is span "test first", than "container"'s classes should be "container first".

Markup looks like that:

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="test first">Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <span class="test second">Some text</span>
</div>
```

My non-working code is:

```
if ($('.container') != null) {
    var sCont = $('.container');
        for (var i = 0; i < sCont.length; i++) {
            if(serviceCont.has('.first').length) {
                sCont.addClass('first')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the code you need, [play with it on Codenpen](http://codepen.io/ji_in_coding/pen/gwyvrW)

```
$(function(){


  $('.container').each(function(){

    if($(this).children('.test.first').length > 0){
      $(this).addClass('first');
    }

    if($(this).children('.test.second').length > 0){
      $(this).addClass('second');
    }

  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.container').length >0) {
    $('.container').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.first').length != 0) {
                $(this).addClass('first')
            }
        });
    }
```

`$('.container')` returns an array with all the elements that match and it needs to be used like an array

Comment: `[i]` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').children.each(function() {
     var parent = $('.container');
     if($(this).hasClass('EnterClassNameHere') {
        parent.addClass('EnterClassNameHere');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, it's pretty simple:

```
$('.test.first').parent('.container').addClass('first');
```

This will look at any elements that have a class of `test` and `first` (so `class="test first"` or `class="first test" doesn't matter).

It'll then get all parents which have a class of `container` and then also give them the class `first`.

If you want all parents regardless, just use `.parent()` without a parameter. If you want to add a different class, just change it. If you want to completely override the class, use `.attr('class', 'first')` instead of `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always the same as you show in your example so :

```js
$('.container').each(function() {
  var span_class = $(this).find('span').attr('class').split(' ')[1];     
  $(this).addClass(span_class);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <span class="test first">Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <span class="test second">Some text</span>
</div>
```

**Output :**

```
<div class="container first">
    <span class="test first">Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="container second">
    <span class="test second">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').each(function() {
  var $cont = $(this);
  $cont.children('span.first').each(function() {
    $cont.addClass('first');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i came up with :

```
 $('.container').each(
 function(){
 var addClass = $(this).children().first().attr('class');
 addClass =addClass.split(' ');
 $(this).addClass(addClass[1]);
 });
```

- Select all div tags with container class.
- Loop through each element.
- Store the classes of first child in a variable.
- This would now be a string, lets split it and get an array.
- I assumed it's the second class of each child you wanna add to the
  parent div tag, if not we can tweak the logic here.

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, use an indexed pattern as a name convention for the ordinal class names.
Instead of: first, second, third...
Use: order-1, order-2, order-3...
Then check all existing children and update their parents:

Given:

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="test order-1">Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <span class="test order-2">Some text</span>
</div>
```

This function will update each parent's class with its child class:

```
function copyStyleClassIntoParent(parentClass, childClass, patternPrefix) {
    var i = 0, $child;
    while (($child = $('.'+childClass+'.'+patternPrefix+(++i))).length) {
        $child.closest('.'+parentClass).addClass(patternPrefix+i);
    }
}

copyStyleClassIntoParent('container', 'test', 'order-');
```

Note: If you intend doing it several times, you should also remove parent obsolete classes with 'removeClass'.